# compilation error ::vector ::iteratator

Tags: c++, sorting, compilation

I encounter this error whenever I compile my prg..

```
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5394:5: note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5430:5: note: void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PointTwoD*, std::vector<PointTwoD> >, _Compare = bool (MissionPlan::*)(PointTwoD&, PointTwoD&)]
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5430:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'bool (MissionPlan::*)(PointTwoD&, PointTwoD&)'
```

Below is actually my .cpp file..

```
bool MissionPlan::sortByCiv(const PointTwoD &t1, const PointTwoD &t2)
{
    return t1.locationdata.getCivIndex() < t2.locationdata.getCivIndex();
}

void MissionPlan::topfives()
{   

    topfive.assign( point1.begin(), point1.end() ); 

    sort(topfive.begin(), topfive.end(), sortByCiv);

    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        topfive.at(i).displayPointdata();
    }

}
```

missionplan.h

```
class MissionPlan
{

    private:
        int sizeofarray;
        int sizeofarray2;
        int xcordi;
        int ycordi;
        LocationData locationdata;
        PointTwoD pointtwoD;
        //MissionPlan missionplan;


    public:
        MissionPlan();
        MissionPlan(int, int, float);

        int getx();
        int gety();
        float civnum;
        float getciv();

        void stats();
        void storedata(int, int, float);
        void test();
        void displayall();
        void compute();
        void topfives();
        static bool sortByCiv(const PointTwoD &t1, const PointTwoD &t2);

};
```

My programme will compile and run smoothly when I remove this line from my code "sort(topfive.begin(), topfive.end(), sortByCiv);"
so is there a problem with that line of code or there other thing that is affecting it?

---

this is the error msg is get when i start compiling after I made sortByCiv statc and change the function para to a const..

```
In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/algorithm:63:0,
                 from ..\src\/MissionPlan.h:9,
                 from ..\src\MissionPlanImp.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h: In function '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PointTwoD*, std::vector<PointTwoD> >, _Tp = PointTwoD, _Compare = bool (*)(PointTwoD&, PointTwoD&)]':
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2265:78:   instantiated from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PointTwoD*, std::vector<PointTwoD> >, _Compare = bool (*)(PointTwoD&, PointTwoD&)]'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2306:62:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PointTwoD*, std::vector<PointTwoD> >, _Size = int, _Compare = bool (*)(PointTwoD&, PointTwoD&)]'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5445:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PointTwoD*, std::vector<PointTwoD> >, _Compare = bool (*)(PointTwoD&, PointTwoD&)]'
..\src\MissionPlanImp.cpp:140:48:   instantiated from here
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2233:4: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'PointTwoD&' from expression of type 'const PointTwoD'
```

### c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2236:4: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'PointTwoD&' from expression of type 'const PointTwoD'

now finally the programme gets to run on command prompt but it gets terminate with the following error msg..

```
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): vecotr::_M_range_check"
```

---

Thanks guys I got it up and running, thanks and appreciate for all ur helps..

Comment: The comparator for `std::sort` must be a non-member function or a class static function

Comment: ... or a properly formed functor (which you should *prefer* to use if organizationally feasible, as it is much more likely to inline in the sort algorithm expansion).

Comment: That's a perfectly usual error message, btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that `sortByCiv` is a member function, which can only be invoked relative to some receiver object (i.e. `myObject.sortByCiv(...)` versus `sortByCiv(...)`. The `std::sort` function expects you to provide as a parameter some function that can be called as a free function with two arguments that will then produce a value.

To fix this, make `sortByCiv` `static`. This makes it no longer have a receiver object and should resolve your issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply.. I actually did make my sortByCiv static in my .h file.. but still can find the problem..

Comment: +1 just want to add that `sortByCiv`does not seem to belong as a member of MissionPlan. The PointTwoD seems to know its own ordering.

Comment: @user2900611 If you did as described here, the error message will not be what is in your question. And your updated content shows you *didn't* do what this answer describes, so start with that first. (and +1 for the answer, btw)

Comment: @user2900611- Can you please update your question to show the exact error you're getting after having made that change? That should have fixed the problem.

Comment: @user2900611- The error message you're describing isn't compatible with the code you have posted. Can you do a clean build and post the updated error message?

Comment: @user2900611 you really need to make sortByCiv parameters const references.

Comment: @templatetypedef I've just changed sortByCiv to static in my .h file and i've already posted the new compilation error msg I received..

Comment: @PavelBeliy i've just updated the error msg and now at least the programms run but crash after the sort function with the following error msg.. 

"terminate called after throwing aninstance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): vector::_M_range_check

Comment: @user2900611- The second error is because you need to make the parameters `const` references. The other error you're getting (the runtime error) should be posted as a separate question as it's probably unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

sortByCiv is a **member function** and it needs special treatment; for instance, you cant cast it to function pointer type, as it has an implicit (third) this-parameter.

And in your case, you don't need to. Just move the sortByCiv(..) out of the class declaration(or make it static), as it doesn't use *this* parameter:

```
bool sortByCiv(const PointTwoD &t1, const PointTwoD &t2)
{
    return t1.locationdata.getCivIndex() < t2.locationdata.getCivIndex();
}
```

Comment: and make parameters of this function const references as i did

Comment: this is actually the new error msg I receive after i change the para to const..


c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2233:4: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'PointTwoD&' from expression of type 'const PointTwoD'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2236:4: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'PointTwoD&' from expression of type 'const PointTwoD'

Comment: i've just updated the error msg and now at least the programms run but crash after the sort function with the following error msg.. 

"terminate called after throwing aninstance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): vector::_M_range_check

Comment: If compilation produced an error, you coudn't run the program to receive a runtime error(as it didn't compile in the first place)... So what is it now?